# Best practice of querying referenced collections?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections, Country, State and City that are structured like this:

`Country 
-> State 
-> -> City`

Here are the schemas:

```
const Country = new Schema(
    {
        disabled: true
    }
);

const State = new Schema(
    {
        countryID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Country"},
        timeZone: String,
        ...
    }
);

const City = new Schema(
    {
        countryID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Country"},
        stateID: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "State"},
        ...
    }
);
```

I've been running the following code to get only the cities that aren't associated with Countries that are disabled:

```
let countryIDs = await Country.find({disabled: false}).distinct("_id");
let stateIDs = await State.find({countryID: {$in: countryIDs}, timeZone: "PST"}).distinct("_id");
let cities = await City.find({stateID: {$in: stateIDs}});
```

When I ran the above code every 20 times a second to run checks using the cities variable, my MongoDB server's CPU was pegged at 100%.

Is there an efficient way to get `City` documents associated with `State` documents that are in a given timezone and are associated with `Country`  documents that are `disabled: false`?

## Update:

The only solution I can think of is to add the `timeZone` and `disabled` fields to the `City` collections.  That way I can just query the `City` collection.  I don't love that idea because I don't want to have to maintain the `timeZone` and `disabled` in multiple locations, seems error prone.  Any other ideas or is that the best approach?

Comment: how many documents do you have in each of these collections?

Comment: country: 1000, state: 2000, city: 12000 but its growing and could grow by a lot.

Comment: You can try `aggregate` in MongoDB

Comment: @IftekharDani, do you have an example?  Would it be more efficient?

Comment: @TomKrones, you would probably like to take a look at data modeling here:https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3. This will avoid making 3 queries to fetch cities with countries not disabled. This should go as one-one relationship b/w cities and countries

Comment: @Astro Just read it, thanks!  Sounds like I should structure the database differently where there is one collection of countries with all the states as an array and all the cities as an array in the states array?  The problem is, the database is already live with users using it.  :/

Comment: You can optimize the queries using indexes if you don't have already: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/. That should help

Comment: @Astro, I'm actually using mongodb.com to host my db and they have a really cool interface that suggests indexes.  Adding the indexes really helped but not enough with this issue.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aggregate` and `lookup`.

```
    db.getCollection('country').aggregate([
{$match :  { "disabled" : true} },
 {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "state",
         localField: "_id",
         foreignField: "countryId",
         as: "state"
       }
  },
  {
  $unwind:
    {
      path: '$state',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
},
{$match : {"state.timeZone" : "PST"}},
  {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "city",
         localField: "state._id",
         foreignField: "stateId",
         as: "city"
       }
  },
  { $group : {
      _id : '$_id',
      disabled : {$first : '$disabled'},
      name : {$first : '$name'},
      state : {$push : '$state'},
      city : {$first : '$city'}
      }
  }
])
```